# Perl (un)pack method in Python

Tags: python, file, templates

Perl has a great couple of methods named: [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html). 
In my case, I'm using them for reading structured files with a template. Take for instance:

File:

```
Date      |Description                | Income|Expenditure
01/28/2001 Flea spray                                24.99
```

And Perl code:

```
my($date,$description,$income) = unpack("A10xA27xA7", $_);
```

This line would retrieve my desired tokens using the template "A10xA27xA7".

The question is: **Is there anything like this in Python?**

Comment: yeah; `struct` module has `pack` and `unpack`

Comment: The problem with `struct` is that it works on bytes objects. If this is a utf-8 encoded file, characters will use a variable number of octets making the field-length numbers meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) has an `unpack` function which does something similar with the `s` format, but it won't trim trailing spaces as Perl's `A` does

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pandas.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) for this like:

```
data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
Date      |Description                | Income|Expenditure
01/28/2001 Flea spray                                24.99"""),
                   header=1, colspecs = [(4, 14), (15, 42), (43, 50)])

print(data))
```

#### Results:

```
         Date Description  Income
0  01/28/2001  Flea spray     NaN
```